# Responsive websites in ipad 3 vs 4

Tags: ipad, responsive-design, media-queries

From my understanding, ipad 2 and maybe 3 had a screen resolution of 1024 whereas ipad 4 has double that.

iPad will still however zoom in to your site and ideally you want your site to look and behave a certain way if it's being viewed on a tablet.

How do you effectively target both these devices using media queries?

@media only screen and (max-width:1024px)

This however won't cover ipad 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they have different resolutions. We have to target particular mediaqueries to handle this. I suggest you to read [this](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/) [article](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/).

Comment: Thanks Akshaya, this article is very useful. I didn't know webkit provided those extra queries. I was looking at the site on a Nokia Lumia and realised that the Lumia has a resolution of 1240x768. Do you know if there are specific queries that cover these scenarios too? It just seems like mobile phones are increasing resolution very fast where it matches the ipad, so it's a bit difficult to judge how to handle these scenarios in an almost device specific way, without actually having to cater for each device.